# SELECT to_char(date_col, 'YYYY-MM') from table - doesn't work in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I'm trying to build a query using **Postgres 9.5.3**

Function `to_char` in simple statement like this

```
SELECT to_char(date_created,'YYYY-MM') FROM some_table;
```

Returns results as follow:

```
+-----------
| to_char
+-----------
| 2017-06
| 2017-07
| 2017-10
```

**Full statement I want to run**

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(
                    to_date('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM'), 
                    to_date('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM'), 
                    interval '1 month') 
AS dates
    WHERE dates NOT IN (
       SELECT to_char(date_created,'YYYY-MM') FROM some_table
    );
```

Result in the following error

> Error in query: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone = text
>   LINE 2: WHERE dates NOT IN (SELECT to_char(date_create,'YYYY-MM')...
>   HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing apples to oranges (timestamps to text).

`generate_series()` with an interval as the third parameter actually returns a `timestamp`, not a `date`. Your sub-select returns the column `date_created` as a string (text) - and comparing a timestamp to a text doesn't work.

As you apparently only want to check for the same month, you need to convert the date returned from `generate_series()` to the same text value:

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(to_date('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM'), 
                     to_date('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM'), 
                     interval '1 month') as dates (d)
WHERE to_char(dates.d, 'yyyy-mm') NOT IN (SELECT to_char(date_created,'YYYY-MM') 
                                          FROM some_table);
```

Another option is to compare dates by "normalizing" the `date_created` to the start of the month:

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(to_date('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM'), 
                     to_date('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM'), 
                     interval '1 month') as dates (d)
WHERE dates.d NOT IN (SELECT date_trunc('month', date_created)
                      FROM some_table);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and your valuable support.

Answer (score 0):

You have a data type mismatch. Use `TO_DATE` to convert right side (inner query) back to `DATE`

```
...
WHERE dates NOT IN (
   SELECT to_date(to_char(date_created,'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM some_table
);
```

or use `TO_CHAR` to convert left side to `CHAR`

```
...
WHERE to_char(dates, 'YYYY-MM')NOT IN (
   SELECT to_char(date_created,'YYYY-MM') FROM some_table
);
```